# Collision detection of sprite with canvas Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>JavaScript</title>
<meta name="description" content="page description">
<meta name="author" content="discoveryvip">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ptc.css">
<canvas id= "canvas" style= "border:1px solid; position:absolute; ">
</canvas>

<div id="sprite"></div>

<style>
#sprite {
width: 135px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url("images/spritesheet.png");
position:absolute;
bottom:1000px;
left:220px;
transition: all 2s;

animation: run 1s steps(5) infinite, slide 4s steps(100) infinite;
margin-right : 100%;

}

@keyframes run {
100% { background-position: -700px;}
}

@keyframes slide {
100% { margin-right: 135px;}

@keyframes slide {
100% { margin-left: -140px;
}

</style>

<script>
var sprite = document.getElementById("sprite");
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");

sprite.style.top = 30 + "px" ;
sprite.style.left = 140 + "px";
sprite.style.height = 100 + "px";
sprite.style.width = 1067 ;
sprite.style.height = 640 ;

document.body.onkeyup = function() {
var e = event.keyCode,
charTop = parseInt(sprite.style.top),
charLeft = parseInt(sprite.style.left);
if (e == 40) { //down function
sprite.style.top = (parseInt(sprite.style.top)) + 20 + "px";
} else if (e == 37) { //left function
sprite.style.left = (parseInt(sprite.style.left)) - 20 + "px";
} else if (e == 39) { //right function
sprite.style.left = (parseInt(sprite.style.left)) + 20 + "px";
} else if (e == 38) { //up function
sprite.style.top = (parseInt(sprite.style.top)) - 20 + "px";

}
}

</script>
```

I am having trouble making the sprite collide with the walls of 
the canvas.

The sprite has been animated through css but it always escapes the canvas walls. I have done some research on collision detection and most code include setting up x and y positions of an object and putting in if statements to check whether it touches the canvas walls but I can't understand how to implement that code onto this sprite.Can anyone please be kind enough to put up an example.

I am still new to javascript and have been at this for weeks.

Comment: Would you be able to create a demo? You can use jsfiddle, codepen or a stack snippet. Thanks

Comment: @ovokuro By demo do you mean like seeing how the code is working?

Answer (score 0):

How about just moving it back if you hit the limit at your move?

```
} else if (e == 37) { 
  //left function
  sprite.style.left = (parseInt(sprite.style.left)) - 20 + "px";
  if(sprite.style.left < 0) 
  {
     sprite.style.left + 20;
  }
}
```

On the right function compare sprite left position + sprite width to canvas width.